# Android try maximize dialog to full screen

Tags: android

I would like to have the dialog to be full screen of the phone. I've tried several method found various places. Coding is :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveBundle) {
    super.onCreate(saveBundle);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    params.height = size.y;
    params.width = size.x;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
}
```

Both setting flag to FLAG_FULLSCREEN and setting the dialog size are not working.
There are spacing on two sides and at the top.

I am able to reduce the spaces by setting the position and size with hard code numbers like:

```
params.x = -30;
params.y = -40;
params.height = size.y + 30;
params.width = size.x + 60;
```

Any suggestion to fix this properly ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this,**

```
dialog = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Transculent_NoTitleBar_FullScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to create your dialog:

```
    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

    wlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify dialogs layout parameters.....

```
localDialog = new Dialog(context);
localDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = localDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
wmlp.width=LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
wmlp.height=LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am Also suffering this problem and I am doing lot's of R&d to set Dialog in full screen but I get Same Result.Lot's of Code working fine but in some device Dialog is not Display Proper.So At the end finally I Decide to Set minHeight and minWidth of Dialog Layout.Following Code is Working fine in My Case.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:minWidth="@dimen/dp_900"
          android:minHeight="@dimen/dp_900"
        >

<!--MY LAYOUT DESIGN-->
```

I hope you are clear with my Idea.

**Best of Luck**